# Pythonic way to hash through dict of dicts dynamically?

Tags: python, dictionary

Suppose I create a dict like so:

```
foods = {}
```

And I eventually want to mutate some value of a nested dict within foods that doesn't yet exist:

```
foods['fruit']['apples'] = ['Granny Smith']
```

Is there a nice way to accomplish this insertion without checking the whole way:

```
if 'fruit' not in foods:
    foods['fruit'] = {}
if 'apples' not in foods['fruit']:
    foods['fruit']['apples'] = []
foods['fruit']['apples'].append('Granny Smith')
```

I guess I'm looking for a way to dynamically hash into nested dicts without explicitly instantiating them along the way.

Comment: This is a duplicate but I can't find the right question yet, but the answer is [collections.defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#defaultdict-examples)

Comment: You'll probably want to use a `defaultdict`, or the regular dictionary's `setdefault()`.

Answer (score 4):

I love the Python standard library. You want to use [collections.defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict).
In this case, you want to nest them, so that `foods` is a `defaultdict` that, on the requested item not existing, generates a `defaultdict` that, on the requested item not existing, generates a list. Sounds complicated, but in the end, the result is not:

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> foods = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(list))
>>> foods['fruit']['apples'].append('Granny Smith')
>>> print(foods['fruit']['apples'])
['Granny Smith']
```

Comment: Thank you for this, very helpful!

Answer (score 3):

Your code:

```
if 'fruit' not in foods:
    foods['fruit'] = {}
if 'apples' not in foods['fruit']:
    foods['fruit']['apples'] = []
foods['fruit']['apples'].append('Granny Smith')
```

would be written as:

```
foods.setdefault('fruit', {}).setdefault('apples', []).append('Granny Smith')
```

Using [`setdefault(key[, default])`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault).

Comment: This is probably a better option than using defaultdict since in this one you are controlling specifically the keys where with defaultdict it will insert any key - so a mis-spelling would still go in

Comment: Somewhat, accesses alone wouldn't create new entries. But this is a drop in replacement for the code that the asker gave as it doesn't require the foods object to be anything but a `dict`. And if the foods object wasn't under our control to create it would be the only option.

Comment: This will create a dictionary object every time regardless of whether the `'fruit'` key already exists.

Comment: But the cost of that is low (0.0324 usecs) (See `python -mtimeit "" "{}"`)